# Cannot create file in external memory Android

Tags: android, file

I have write this..

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), myFileName);

        if(file.exists()) {
            createDelete.setText("Delete file");
            Toast.makeText(SaveToFile.this, myFileName+" auto-created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(!file.exists()) 
            Toast.makeText(SaveToFile.this, myFileName+" auto-creation failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

When i run it, it make the failed toast. I can't find the file in directory (neither emulator or my phone).

Permision added in manifest, version is 8. Emulator has 512 MB external memory.

Comment: plz post logcat error

Comment: There is no error or warning on logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    //handle case of no SDCARD present
} else {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
         +File.separator
         +"myDirectory" //folder name
         +File.separator
         +"myFile.example"); //file name
    file.mkdirs();
}
```

and in your manifest..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the file you have to call mkdir

```
File file = new File(Environment..getExternalStorageDirectory(), myFileName);
// To create the file
file.mkdir();
```

Since mkdir is a boolean, you can also do this

```
if (file.mkdir()) {
    Toast.makeText(SaveToFile.this, myFileName+" auto-created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(SaveToFile.this, myFileName+" auto-creation failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

If you have some sub-directories, use **mkdirs()**, it will create missing sub-directories

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29

Comment: tnx a lot! i dont know for sure but i think that file.exists() maybe is buggy.

Answer (score -1):

**Do this way**

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // Update HEre
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + myFileName);

        if(file.exists()) {
            createDelete.setText("Delete file");
            Toast.makeText(SaveToFile.this, myFileName+" auto-created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            file.createNewFile(); //UPDATE HERE
        }
        else if(!file.exists()) 
            Toast.makeText(SaveToFile.this, myFileName+" auto-creation failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: I added it, but nothing changed.